# How to set default headers to resolve 422 status code error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

It is my first time working with API. I have a following data. I need to POST register data to API and GET on login. But when I try to post data to API but get a 422 Status code error. I guess I have to set headers but didn't know where have to and how to get access-token and get on Login. IS there have any video tutorial or docs about them?

```
 'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,
    ]
    'api' => [
        [
            'method' => 'post',
            'url' => 'URL/api/register',
            'params' => [
                'query' => null,
                'body' => [
                    'phone' => ['max:255'],
                    'password' => ['min:7'],
                    'cnd' => ['0|1'],
                ]
            ],
            'response' => [
                'data' => [
                    'data':null,
                    'message':'Successfully created user!',
                    'errors':null
                ],
                'status' => 201
            ]
        ],
        [
            'method' => 'post',
            'url' => 'http://localhost:8000/api/login',
            'params' => [
                'query' => null,
                'body' => [
                    'phone' => ['max:255'],
                    'password' => ['min:7'],
                ]
            ],
            'response' => [
                'data' => [
                    'data': [
                        'access_token': 'xxxx',
                        'token_type': 'Bearer',
                        'expires_at': 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS'
                    ],
                    'message': 'User login successfully.',
                    'errors': null
                ],
                'status' => 200
            ]
        ]
```

React Code

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import './SignUp.style.scss'
import eyeClosed from '../img/eye-closed.svg'
import eyeOpen from '../img/eye-open.svg'
import axios from 'axios'

const SignUp = () => {

    const [type, setType] = useState(false)
    const [password, setPassword] = useState(false)
    const [email, setEmail] = useState()

   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        

        axios.post('https://mb.unitedskills.space/api/register', {
            phone: email,
            password: password,
            cnd:1
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

    }

    return (
        <form className='login-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-control">
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input spellcheck="false" onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} type="email" name="email" id="email" />
            <small>&nbsp;</small>             
        </div>

        <div className="form-control">
            <label className="password-label" htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            <div className="password-container">
                <input spellcheck="false" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} type={type ? 'text' : 'password'} className="password" name="password" id="password" />
                <span className="eye"><img onClick={e => setType(!type)} src={type ? eyeOpen : eyeClosed} alt="eye icon" /></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button className="submit-btn" >Register</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default SignUp
```

Answer (score 0):

Before all, create a new axios file, and do something like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'https://yourapi.com/';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: url,
});

const revalidateToken = async () => {
  const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('@Api:refreshToken');
  await axios
    .post(`${url}token`, {
      refreshToken,
    })
    .then((config) => {
      localStorage.setItem('@Api:acessToken', config.data.accessToken);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return error;
    });
};

api.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('@Api:acessToken');

  if (token) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }

  return config;
});

api.interceptors.response.use(
  async (config) => {
    return config;
  },
  async (error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      await revalidateToken();
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

export default api;
```

Comment: Answers which explain changes to code (the "why") are more often upvoted and less often downvoted than those which simply copy and paste code from some other location. For instance, the OP is not currently using localStorage, so introducing that without explanation is not terribly helpful...

Comment: @Bruno that was so confused for me and I think it does not related my question. Google is full of such an examples.But thanks anyway.